# asp.net ConvertTimeFromUtc inside of .ASPX file

Tags: asp.net

Inside of my .aspx file, I need to convert the date that I get to the local date as it is stored as UTC

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:phiSQL %>"                
    SelectCommand="select ID, AnalasisDate from ProgTbl"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDS1" Width="1200px"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_OnRowCommand" 
    AllowSorting="True">
       <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID"  HeaderText="Identification"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AnalasisDate"  HeaderText="Time Stamp"/>
         ...
```

I know doing something like

```
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(result.AnalasisDate.Value, tz)
```

will do it but not sure how to incorporate this in the .aspx file.

I tried the following:

```
     <Columns>  

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Stamp"/>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <%= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(AnalasisDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Session["Timezone"].ToString()))  %>
         </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
```

but getting a message that Code blocks not supported in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably use a TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Stamp"/>
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("AnalasisDate")).ToLocalTime() %>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hello, I added additional code but still getting an error. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax:

```
<%= [your code]  %>
```

For example:

```
<%= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(result.AnalasisDate.Value, tz)  %>
```

Comment: Hello, I added additional code but still getting an error. Please advise

Comment: It's not the problem of syntax. 
Because this works well *<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>*

Answer (score 0):

@codingbiz => That answer will work for the server-side. `ToLocalTime()`
converts the time to timezone of the server. Could be a solution when you want the timezone from the server and you know where the server stands.

If you want to show the time from the Client-side you have to do something more. Like asking in which timezone the user is by an input-value. Or if you know where the user is, you can use his timezone id-sting:

```
<%= DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc,
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")) %>
```

Here you can find all the TimeZoneID's:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/gg154758.aspx